# How to create a new project without Gradle support?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

Is it possible to create a new project without gradle support in Android Studio, i.e. likewise in Intellij IDEA IDE?

Comment: I have not found a way, but you could just use IntelliJ to create the project and then import it into AS. Bit of a pain, but workable :)

Comment: What @free3dom suggests works, you just get the "Migrate Project to Gradle?" pop-up after the import, but you can choose to "Don't show this message again".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As far as I understand android studio is dependent on gradle as the build engine, and therefore you couldn't create an android project without gradle support

Comment: I use Android Studio **without** gradle, but my project was created using IntelliJ and then imported into AS. Android Studio still works perfectly without using gradle - so it is definitely not *required*.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way only: create new project with IDEA and reopen in AS :-(

Unfortunately, I don't know such preference or option in AS. If you found it, please comment.

ps.s Gradle is a big pain at least in current AS beta 0.8, I spent more than 80% work time to fight with it's fatal issues. I think Google team must make AS more and more friendly to developers, never used gradle.

Comment: Would doing "Import Project" on a folder containing only AndroidManifest.xml work (xml created manually)?